# Rails use ActiveRecord to make a generic select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A simple question: normally we search for entities using active record, for example:

```
Book.where(where).joins(join).order(order).limit(10)
```

But sometimes we don't want to return a book. I just wanted to use this syntax to make a query that returns an array of maps, with the fields on select, without bounding it to any entity. Is it possible? Is there a magial Default class, on which I can do something like:

```
Default.select(select).from('book').where(where).joins(join).group(group).order(order)
```

It would be nice to keep the standard acrross the code, even in reports that do not relate to entities.

Normally I do it in the from table entity, but that has some drawbacks: once I specify the exact fields I want in select, I end up with a corrupted, incomplete entity. Also, it seems to always return the id in the .to_json. It would be nice to get just an array of maps.

Array of maps is just an arrray, but instead of objects is has maps inside:
[ {id: 12, name: 'Luan'}, {id: 42, foo: 'Bar'} ]
Note that I don't want to use the Book entity because I am not returning a Book: I am returning certain columns from multiple tables being joined, for a particular purpose, that are not being represented by a single entity. That is why I wanted to return an array of maps, and, in particular, do not use the Book class or any other entity class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by array of maps (two dimensional array?) but if you only want certain fields I would suggest looking into [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

Comment: On both of your suggestion I'd need to do Book.find_by_sql or Book.pluck, correct? I don't want to use the Book entity because I am not returning a Book, but I'd like to be able to use these methods .where, .joins, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an annoying part of ActiveRecord. As an example of how messed up it is:

```
query = Task.select("tasks.*, projects.*, 'test' AS something").joins(:project)
query.each do |task|
  puts task # Task
  puts task.id # is this the Task#id or the Project#id, no way to know for sure
  puts task.something # not a real attribute of Task
end
```

You can create a model called `Query` and use that as the 'root' query object, sort of a lame hack as it will need to create a database table as well

OR use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` directly, for example

```
sql = Book.where(where).joins(join).order(order).to_sql
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

# rows is a PGResult object in my case
rows.each do |row|
  puts row # Hash
  puts row[:id] # nil
  puts row["id"] # 1
end
```